# SDL_Renderer works as global variable, but not if declared in main, and passed to the functions that require it instead

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, reference

I've been going back over some SDL tutorials I did a while back to practice pointers/references, but I got stuck on something.

If I declare the SDL_Renderer globally everything works, but if I try to declare it in main, and pass the renderer to the functions that need it, I eventually get an SDL_Error saying "invalid renderer".

What works:

```
...
// Global vars
SDL_Window* gWindow = NULL;

SDL_Renderer* gRenderer = NULL;

SDL_Rect gSpriteClips[ 4 ];
LTexture gSpriteSheetTexture;
...

// called from main after SDL initialization
bool loadMedia()
{
    bool success = true;

    //Load sprite sheet texture
    if( !gSpriteSheetTexture.loadFromFile( gRenderer, "img/dots.png" ) )
    {
        printf( "Failed to load sprite sheet texture!\n" );
        success = false;
    }
...
```

What doesn't work:

```
...
bool init( SDL_Window* window, SDL_Renderer* renderer, const int SCREEN_WIDTH, const int SCREEN_HEIGHT )
{
    ...
}
...
bool load_media( SDL_Renderer* renderer, LTexture& sprite_sheet_texture, SDL_Rect* sprite_clips )
{
    bool success = true;

    //Load sprite sheet texture
    if( !sprite_sheet_texture.loadFromFile( renderer, "img/dots.png" ) )
    {
        printf( "Failed to load sprite sheet texture!\n" );
        success = false;
    }
...

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
    const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

    SDL_Window* window = NULL;

    SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;
    
    SDL_Rect sprite_clips[ 4 ];
    LTexture sprite_sheet_texture;
    
    if( !init( window, renderer, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT ) )
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        if( !load_media( renderer, sprite_sheet_texture, sprite_clips ) )
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to load media!\n";
        }
...
```

The texture class: (same file for both versions)

```
bool LTexture::loadFromFile( SDL_Renderer* gRenderer, const std::string &path )
{
    // Get rid of preexisting texture
    free();

    // The final texture
    SDL_Texture* newTexture = NULL;

    // Load image at specified path
    SDL_Surface* loadedSurface = IMG_Load( path.c_str() );

    if( loadedSurface == NULL )
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to load image! SDL_Image error: " << IMG_GetError() << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        // color key image
        SDL_SetColorKey( loadedSurface, SDL_TRUE, SDL_MapRGB( loadedSurface->format, 0, 0xFF, 0xFF ) );

        // Create texture from surface pixels
        newTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( gRenderer, loadedSurface ); <-- POINT OF FAILURE
        
        if( newTexture == NULL )
        {
            std::cout << "Unable to create texture! SDL error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl; <-- THE ERROR I GET
        }
...
```

The way I see it, SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface expects a pointer to an SDL_Renderer, which is what I'm passing. I don't understand why it matters if it's globally declared or declared in main. It should still just be a chunk of memory I'm pointing to somewhere.
I understand I must be passing it wrong, but I can't figure out how to do it correctly, and everything I've tried has produced the same error (passing the pointer as a reference, as a pointer to the pointer, etc.).

Side-note: I know I could just declare it globally or create a Singleton and be done with it, but this is more a learning exercise for me - so the point is to understand the pointer/reference aspect of the problem.

Comment: In the second code snippet (the one which doesn't work), are you passing the variable `renderer` by value or by reference to the function `init`? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Same method as load_media - so if my understanding is correct, I'm passing a pointer? I create it as a pointer, and I don't dereference it, so it's still a pointer right? I updated the example.

Comment: In the second snippet, if `init` changes the variable `renderer`, it will only change its local copy of the variable. It will not change the original variable `renderer` in the function `main`. This is because you are passing the variable [by value](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_value.htm). If you instead pass it [by pointer](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_pointer.htm) or [by reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_reference.htm), you will also modify the original variable's value.

Comment: Note that in order to pass a pointer to another function by pointer, you will need a pointer to a pointer, i.e. an `SDL_Renderer **`.

Comment: Okay - if I pass the SDL_Window and SDL_Renderer around as pointers to pointers (**) and add *'s to where they appear in those functions, it works as intended, but I sorta lost track of the flow.

I'm creating them as pointers to SDL-structs, then I pass those pointers as pointers to functions, and add the * everywhere because they're still pointers to the pointers I create in main?

Comment: If you don't want to add `*` everywhere in your functions, you can use references instead. You can make `init` take a reference to an `SDL_Renderer`, i.e an `SDL_Renderer *&`. References are technically the same as pointers, but the syntax is easier.

Comment: I might do that. But either solution, memory-wise I'm still only throwing around an address right?

Comment: Yes, internally, your program will be working with addresses, even if you are using references instead of pointers.

Comment: Note that you only need to pass a variable by pointer/reference to a function if that function is supposed to modify the original variable. Otherwise, it is sufficient to pass the variable by value.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This has really improved my understanding of pointers/references!

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that one of my comments above is missing a `*`. I meant that `init` can take a reference to an `SDL_Renderer*`, i.e. an `SDL_Renderer*&`. Unfortunately, I cannot edit the comment anymore to fix it, because the comment is more than 5 minutes old.

Comment: Your explanation of why you must add `*` everywhere in your functions is correct. When passing a variable by pointer or reference to another function, you are passing the address of the original variable to the function. That is why you must dereference that address using `*` everywhere in the function. However, this is only necessary when passing by pointer. When passing by reference, the address must also be dereferenced, but this is done automatically, so you don't have to use the dereference-operator `*` explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second snippet, if `init` changes the variable `renderer`, it will only change its local copy of the variable. It will not change the original variable `renderer` in the function `main`. This is because you are passing the variable [by value](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_value.htm). If you instead pass it [by pointer](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_pointer.htm) or [by reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_reference.htm), you will also modify the original variable's value. That way, your program will behave the same way as your global variable version.

Note that in order to pass a pointer to another function by pointer, you will need a pointer to a pointer. In your case you will need an `SDL_Renderer **`.

Comment: It works now. I can't say it's not still a litte confusing, but I feel like understanding it is within my grasp if I stare at it a little longer.

I updated the question with a working solution based on your answer.

Comment: @SproedAsfalt: Instead of answering your own question inside the question, it seems more appropriate to write a formal answer to your question. See this official help page for further information: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Thanks. I thought that was only for if you solve it before another answer is submitted. I moved it to a separate answer now.

Comment: @SproedAsfalt: I think it is much cleaner now, as a proper answer. There are no restrictions on posting answers. Of course, you should not post an additional answer if everything has already been said in the existing answers and you have nothing of value to add. But if you want to post a working solution and no working solution has been posted yet, then there is nothing wrong with posting an additional answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the answer and advice by Andreas Wenzel, I now have a working solution. I thought I was passing by pointer, when I was actually passing by value. By passing a pointer to a pointer instead it works as intended.

I've included snippets below to show the difference from the code in the original question.

```
int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
    const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

    SDL_Window* window = NULL;

    SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;
    
    SDL_Rect sprite_clips[ 4 ];
    LTexture sprite_sheet_texture;
    
    if( !init( &window, &renderer, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT ) )
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        if( !load_media( &renderer, sprite_sheet_texture, sprite_clips ) )
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to load media!\n";
        }

...

bool init( SDL_Window** window, SDL_Renderer** renderer, const int SCREEN_WIDTH, const int SCREEN_HEIGHT )
{
    bool success = true;

    // initialize SDL
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0 )
    {
        std::cout << "SDL could not initialize! SDL error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        success = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if( !SDL_SetHint( SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "1" ) )
        {
                std::cout << "Warning: Linear texture filtering not enabled!\n";
        }

        // Create window
        *window = SDL_CreateWindow( 
                "SDL Tutorial",
                SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                SCREEN_WIDTH,
                SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN
                );

        if( window == NULL )
        {
            std::cout << "Window could not be created! SDL error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
            success = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Create renderer for window
            *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer( *window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED );
            if( renderer == NULL )
            {
                std::cout << "Renderer could not be created! SDL error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
                success = false;
            }

...

bool load_media( SDL_Renderer** renderer, LTexture& sprite_sheet_texture, SDL_Rect* sprite_clips )
{
    bool success = true;

    //Load sprite sheet texture
    if( !sprite_sheet_texture.loadFromFile( *renderer, "img/dots.png" ) )
    {
        printf( "Failed to load sprite sheet texture!\n" );
        success = false;
    }

...

void close( SDL_Window** window, SDL_Renderer** renderer )
{
    //Destroy Window
    SDL_DestroyRenderer( *renderer );
    SDL_DestroyWindow( *window );
    *window = NULL;
    *renderer = NULL;

    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

Comment: There is no need for the function `load_media` to receive the variable `renderer` by pointer. It is sufficient to receive it by value, because it does not write to it. However, what you are doing is not wrong. If you prefer to keep it this way for consistency, you can.

Comment: Is that still true, when the texture object's .loadFromFile() has to write to the renderer? Would it make sense to pass it through load_media by value, then by pointer to sprite_sheet_texture.loadFromFile?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `"write to the renderer"`? Do you mean change the value of the original variable `renderer` in the function `main`? Or do you mean performing an SDL action on the renderer, such as loading textures into the graphics card (i.e. a `"graphical write"`)?

Comment: I might have confused myself. I thought the renderer was updated in the texture class, but I can see it's just passed again to an SDL function to create a texture. I thought it was being updated, because that's where I got the error before, but the error probably came because I was passing an empty renderer.

Comment: Yes, the error you were getting was probably because you were passing the variable `renderer` from the function `main` which had the value `NULL`. This value was not being updated by the function `init` due to being passed by value, so `init` was only updating its own copy of `renderer`.